# Acute angle and trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given that $\theta$ is an acute angle and $\cos\theta = \dfrac{7}{25}$. Find: $\tan\theta$, $\sin\theta$, $\sec\theta$.

Comment: Another way, since $0<\theta<\dfrac\pi2$, we can use
\begin{align}
&\color{blue}{(1)}\;\;\cos\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
&\color{blue}{(2)}\;\;\sin\theta=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
&\color{blue}{(3)}\;\;\tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}\\
&\color{blue}{(4)}\;\;\sec\theta=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y}\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**
\begin{align}
&\color{blue}{(1)}\;\;\;\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}\\[15pt]
&\color{blue}{(2)}\;\;\;\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\\[15pt]
&\color{blue}{(3)}\;\;\;\sec\theta=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Aww...you were fast!

Comment: Shouldn't the first equation be $\sin\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$? (The sign depending on the quadrant.) EDIT: Sorry, now I have noticed that original post says that $\theta$ is an accute angle.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I take the positive value since $\theta$ is acute.  **Edit :** It's OK. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: an alternative to (2) would be $\tan\theta=\sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1}$